# Unit testing injectable services

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-runner, nomachine-nx

I am having problems while performing a simple unit test in my NX workspace. What I am attempting to do is to 1) configure TestBed and 2) Inject service. However, even if I use scaffolded dummy service, the test still fails as the injected service is said to be `undefined`

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  constructor() { }
}
```

test.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ TestService ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
  });
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Does anybody have an idea why is this happening? What exactly is the problem here?

**Edit:**
Yes, I do know I can create a mock. However, the issue still seems strange to me so I would like to get to the bottom of it rather than finding a workaround.

**Edit 2:**
Using `ng test <project> --test-file=<filename>` directly yields the same results are using NXCLI to perform tests

**Edit 3:** I shared my code on StackBlitz as requested: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-unittest-issue

Comment: It works for me. You don't need to add service to providers array

Comment: I have no nx project and can't test it locally, but a co-worker of mine said he had the same problem and fixed it by settings `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` inside `tsconfig.spec.json`. Give it a shot, maybe that solves your issue :)

Comment: How do you suggest we run your stackblitz to see the issue - when I open it, it's running your component, not the tests? If I modify your stackblitz to run the tests, then it all seems to work fine

Answer (score 7):

I've passed through the exact same issues, where the service was `undefined` when being tested.
What solved my problem here were two things:

1. If you are using Jest, make sure you remove `jest.mock('@angular/core/testing')` from your code. This was required on earlier versions.
2. If you have any other injections on your service, you have to add them to 'providers' under `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Here is a sample functional code and unit testing for a simple Http service, tested on Angular 9 and Angular 10:

**api.service.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  baseUrl = 'https://my-api-url.com';

  //api/getId/:id
  getDataById(id: number): Observable<DataSample[]> {
    return this.http.get<DataSample[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/getId/${id}`);
  }
}

export interface DataSample {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**api.service.spec.ts**

```js
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ApiService, DataSample } from './api.service';

describe('ApiService tests', () => {
  let service: ApiService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ApiService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ApiService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => httpMock.verify());

  it('should return an Observable<DataSample[]>', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();

    const id: number = 1;
    const mockResult: DataSample[] = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2',
      },
    ];
    const expectedUrl = `https://my-api-url.com/getId/${id}`;

    service
      .getDataById(id)
      .subscribe((res) => expect(res).toBe(mockResult));

    const req = httpMock.expectOne(expectedUrl);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(mockResult);
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great!
complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not correct for getting the service instance because you didn't provide your serivce.

I used to get the instance like below:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [TestService]
});
service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
```

Comment: Still undefined. I updated the original post though as the service should 100% be a provider in the TestBed

Comment: what is your angular version?

Comment: I use Angular 9.0.0

Comment: it must work really, can you upload your code to stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your TestBed configuration so the way I would have approach this is

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;
  beforeEach(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declaration:[], // your component here
     imports: [], 
     providers: [TestService], // your services here   
  });

  service = TestBed.get(TestService); // to get the service instance
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I adjusted the sample based on suggestion from @yash. For some reason, even adding the service as a provider does not work (which is just odd). I tried adding empty `declarations` and `imports`, thinking that it might be some sort of brainfart of the TestBed, but that did not help either.

Comment: Have you tired `service = TestBed.get(TestService)` this intead of `service = TestBed.inject(TestService)`

Comment: Yes (even though it's deprecated)