# How to inject dependencies in Jest tests, injected with the new Angular14 inject function?

Tags: angular, ts-jest

I refactored all my components' constructors with the new inject function from Angular v14+

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmpt',
  templateUrl: './cmpt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmpt.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private fb = inject(NonNullableFormBuilder);
  private service = inject(MyService);
  private router = inject(Router);

  // constructor(
  //   private fb: NonNullableFormBuilder,
  //   private service: MyService,
  //   private router: Router
  // ) {}
```

I were testing like this (when dependencies were injected in component constructor)

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let nnfb = new FormBuilder().nonNullable;
  let serviceSpy: any;
  let routerMock: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    serviceSpy = {
      get: jest.fn(),
      update: jest.fn(),
      delete: jest.fn()
    };
    
    // I can't inject deps anymore using constructor in tests ?
    component = new MyComponent(nnfb, serviceSpy, routerMock);
  });

  ...
```

While using this new inject function sounds a nice syntactic sugar, i'm clueless how to to adapt my tests with this new injection syntax ?

EDIT: i used Jest to abandon Testbed or any Angular related testing stuff, much more verbose and slower ... but now looks likei'm facing an incompatibility issue between Jest and the new inject() from Angular14 ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing injectable services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172146/unit-testing-injectable-services)

Comment: and https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+inject+jest+testing

Comment: Use `Testbed` and the `providers` array which will result in the angular framework taking care of your DI.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i don't want testbed or any Angular related stuff in tests (or the least required)

I've already googled before coming here, all i've found is @Inject or testBed related stuff, which is not at all my issue...

i've tried extending beforeEach(inject([ nnfb, serviceSpy, routerMock ], () => ... but still facing issue that deps are not injected inside component's implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spectator: https://github.com/ngneat/spectator - it seems to work fine with Angular 14's inject function